# Помогите последовательно воспроизвести медиафайлы

Tags: java, android, for, android-mediaplayer

Сразу запускаются все медиафайлы, а не последовательно(должно запустится 5 аудиофайлов, а за ними еще 2 раза по 5), но запускаются сразу 3
Не получается запустить всё последовательно помогите пожалуйста разобраться
Без while всё работает последоватльно

```
while (a<3) {

                         CreateRandom();
                         StartMedia();
                         a++;
                     }

public void StartMedia(){

    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer1.start();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer2.start();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer3.start();
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer3.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer4.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Целых 4 плеера о_О

Comment: Да))) Извините,но работает всё забавно, могу на гитхаб ссылку дать

Comment: Делаете плеер и номер последнего трека static полями, составляете плейлист в массиве/коллекции, при окончании воспроизведения инкременируйте номер последнего трека и воспроизводите, но если трек был последний то, или заново, или что хотите.

Comment: Он заново должен запускаться и возможно я криво сделал, но спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Вместе трёх раз решил сделать вот так, функция будет запускаться до определенного действия
Возможно криво и неправильно, но приложение работает и не вылетает

```
 public void StartMedia(){


    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer1.start();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer2.start();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer3.start();
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer3.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer4.start();
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer4.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            stopSounds();
            CreateRandom();
            StartMedia();
        }
    });
}
```